# When does sql server update index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

When we insert multiple rows or update multiple rows, does SQL server updates the index for each row (one after one) or does it update the index for multiple rows after query executes?

Comment: The index updates and the data updates take effect at the same time.  That is how transactions work.

Comment: you mean, if the query is inserting 10 rows, the index will be updated once for all the 10 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They always gets updated within the same transaction - never "after [the] query executes"

The plan may be either a wide (per index) plan that updates one index completely then moves on to the next one or a narrow (per row) one that updates all affected indexes for one row then all for the next row and so on. See [Wide vs. Narrow Plans](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2006/07/27/wide-vs-narrow-plans/) for more about this.